# How to save value of HiddenField in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, hiddenfield

I want to save the value of my HiddenField in the database. But I don't know what comes after the comma.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hfLat", what goes here?)
```

I tried:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hfLat", HiddenField.Value); // Doesn't work.
```

html:

```html
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLat" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Id of hiddenfield hfLat.Value.

Comment: You may want to add more details to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to access control via Id which is ***hfLat*** in this case.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hfLat", hfLat.Value);
```